# DELPHI - Is there a way to free an object created at runtime without getting 'Access Violation?'

Tags: delphi, runtime, pascal

this problem is driving me crazy, i have an edit box in which i write something. On event 'change' of edit box, a ListBox is created and filled by SQL query. It works as a hint box while writing.
When i hit enter on the item which i want to select, the listbox should 'free', but it continues to return me 'access violation'. Here the code:

```
procedure TFTimbra.EditCommessaKeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word;
  Shift: TShiftState);
var
  X, Y, W: Integer;
  QSugg: TAdoQuery;
begin
  if not Assigned(Suggerimento) then
  begin
    Suggerimento := TListBox.Create(Self);
    Y := EditCommessa.Top + EditCommessa.Height;
    X := EditCommessa.Left;
    W := EditCommessa.Width;

    with Suggerimento do
    begin
      Top := Y;
      Left := X;
      Width := W;
      Height := 200;
      Parent := FTimbra;
      BorderStyle := bsNone;
      Font.Size := 14;
      Font.Style := [fsBold];
    end;
  end else
    Suggerimento.Clear;

  if Key = 40 then
    Suggerimento.SetFocus;

  QSugg := TAdoQuery.Create(nil);
  QSugg.ConnectionString := DMMain.DBConnection.ConnectionString;
  QSugg.SQL.Text := format('select Codice, Descrizione from Commesse where Descrizione like %s', 
    [quotedstr('%' + EditCommessa.Text + '%')]);
  QSugg.Open;

  while not QSugg.Eof do
  begin
    Suggerimento.Items.Add(QSugg.FieldByName('Descrizione').AsString);
    QSugg.Next;
  end;

  QSugg.Close;
  if Assigned(Suggerimento) then Suggerimento.OnKeyDown := SuggerimentoKeyDown;
end;
```

This is the first part, and this is the code that "should" free the listbox:

```
procedure TFTimbra.SuggerimentoKeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word;
  Shift: TShiftState);
begin
  if Key = 13 then
  begin
    Commessa := Suggerimento.Items[Suggerimento.ItemIndex];
    EditCommessa.Text := Commessa;
    Suggerimento.Free;
  end;
end;
```

I think the problem is in the call of the OnKeyDown function.. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Add a `Suggerimento := nil` after the call to `Suggerimento.Free;` Otherwise your Assigned check will still return true.

Comment: Without wishing to set off a war, you could also use `FreeAndNil(Suggerimento)`

Comment: It doesn't work.. i tried with Suggerimento := nil/ FreeAndNil(Suggerimento).
In debug mode with breakpoint, it runs fine until the 'end' of SuggerimentoKeyDown procedure..

Comment: This code looks to me like bunch of lines randomly put together as if you don't understand what's going on in there. And that's why you have bug(s) in it that you need to fix. Apart from that it also leaks memory (`QSugg`) upon each keystroke.

Comment: Here the error: https://imgur.com/a/PI3zhgY

Comment: @PeterWolf, these are not lines randomly put togheter, there is a logic and all works fine except this little thing.

Comment: I can only guess, but I dont know if delphi handles it all too well if the object is freed within its own OnKeyDown event. You might want to try and find another place to free it.

Comment: Oops, I didn't see that, but yeah, can't free and object while one of its events is executing. Don't create / destroy this object. Let it be created when the form is created in the normal way (via the dfm). And simple show / hide it. Or equivalently set `Visible` true or false.

Comment: Okay, i will do it by DFM and show/hide it, thank you @DavidHeffernan

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Well, `X.Free; X := nil` should always be written as `FreeAndNil(X)` IMHO, because the latter is safer: if `X.Destroy` raises an exception (which it absolutely should not do, but which may happen in practice, especially if you use unreliable third-party code), `FreeAndNil(X)` will still set `X` to `nil`, thus avoiding further memory issues in the future. I do realise some people might disagree, though.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand It's pointless trying to defend against destructors that raise exceptions. Once that happens it's over.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't destroy an object from one of that object's own event handlers. When the event handler returns, the code continues executing in the context of the object, which you just freed. And that typically leads to runtime errors like this.

Rather than use a dynamic lifetime for this list box control, create it in the traditional way, using the form designer. When you want it hidden, set `Visible` to `False`. When you want it to show, set `Visible` to `True`.